# Is there something wrong with my Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm following the developer.android.com instructions for installing Eclipse ADT. I think I may not have installed it correctly, however, as I've got to a stage where I'm told to click the SDK Manager icon in the Eclipse toolbar and it's not there.

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC you can't get to the SDK Manager from Eclipse. You have to go to the directory the SDK was installed in and then open `SDKManager.exe`. But I can't remember if that's true or not...

Comment: You should also be able to find it under "Window" -> "Android SDK Manager", if your Eclipse is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an instance of Eclipse dedicated to android development, I recommend downloading a pre-configured eclipse here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

If you just want to add the ADT plugin to eclipse, it's also pretty simple.. I'm assuming you're following the directions here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

If you've done the help-->install new software--> etc.--> restart eclipse, and still can't find it, then I would make sure that you are in JAVA perspective. Also, make sure that you've configured the SDK as well.

Comment: Thanks, opening the Java perspective seems to have given me what I wanted. I can now see the icons I should have. I installed this last summer and didn't have to that before though.